# How to compile Unity3D script to include it to AssetBundle?

Tags: unity-game-engine

According to this [manual](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/AssetBundles) I can include scripts as binary data and load them via Reflection. I understand all steps, except one: how can I compile script to get binary data for stroring it in .binary file? Is there any tutorial/help?

**UPD:**
Actual question can be restated as: "How can I compile single file with MonoDevelop and get its bytecode"

Comment: I've asked this in both places. There is [unity3d] tag, so some people can help me. If I'll find answer myself, I'm going to post it here to help google index this question.

Comment: From the link you provided: `You can create your assemblies in any normal C# IDE (e.g. Monodevelop, Visual Studio) or any text editor using the mono/.net compilers.`

Comment: I've updated the question. Actually I can't find how to compile single file with monodevelop and get its bytecode

Comment: Now that should be a question that somebody can answer.  I've never used MonoDevelop, but I get this after a quick google: `http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

1. Open Monodevelop and create C#Library project
2. Add UnityEngine.dll to References
3. Compile your scripts
4. Copy bin/.dll from your library project folder to Assets of your unity project and change extension from .dll to .bytes

That's all.