# Unity C# Precompile and Mono Reflection

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project using Unity 3d. This project is an Application for android and it will download AssetBundles and load their content, but since AssetBundles cannot contain scripts, I will use precompiled C# script and use Mono Reflection to load it (I have no idea how but I would figure it out). But now I don't know how to precompile a .cs file, so can anyone help me with this?

Comment: did you search before posting ? :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808033/how-to-compile-unity3d-script-to-include-it-to-assetbundle

Comment: I did, and all I found was answers about how to compile and run a C# program .. but my question is more specific about how to produce a binary precompiled file from a class .. if you have a reference that I missed please direct me to it

Comment: Got it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808033/how-to-compile-unity3d-script-to-include-it-to-assetbundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile your script in MonoDevelop/VisualStudio as a .dll, copy your script.dll to Assets folder of your Unity project and **change the extension from .dll to .bytes**