# Unity3D how to support 'modding' (allowing players to add their own game objects)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

I'd like users to be able to **design** their own GameObjects in unity, and somehow **import** them at runtime into a game I'm making.

That means *maintaining the hierarchy (there may be child objects), and any scripts, components, models, and materials used*.

After looking around, I haven't seen any cookie-cutter solutions to this problem, but I also have a hard time believing I'm the first person to attempt to write a moddable game with Unity's engine. Are there any best practices for adding prefabs/assets at runtime?

Comment: I doubt you'll find any "cookie-cutter solutions" to such a task, if I'm honest. Allowing the use of mods, is an entirely new ball-game. Models etc, this is easy enough, designate a directory, and simply load anything that's in there. But allowing custom code, will require extra efforts, such as external support for scripting engines etc, such as Lua.

Comment: @LokiSinclair I've seen examples of C# being compiled dynamically before, so I'm hoping I don't have to turn to Lua or something similar!

Comment: Well, I'm sure you could, but for maximum exposure a scripting language offers a lot more benefits. I personally wouldn't limit a project to compilation only. There are already a few Lua assets for unity, then you just expose content for people to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) are the way to go.

Basically you can create one or multiple assetbundle files from scenes or specific objects which pack everything into them.

Assetbundles contain everything you want, except **new** scripts. You can reference scripts but not create them per default.

If you want to bundle new scripts you need to [create a ddl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808033/how-to-compile-unity3d-script-to-include-it-to-assetbundle) and load that during runtime.